# Python : Appending series to dataframe does not place the data in the correct columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

Super long story short! My output csv file has the data in the wrong columns!

I have hundreds of files daily to ingest. For testing purposes, i am only using one file.

Within each file, I have multiple features. Each file is the dimensional inspection of a part and for each part there are multiple features being inspected.

I create the blank output csv file with the headers

I loop through each file

----I loop through each feature within that file

--------I append the data for each feature to a dataframe

----I append that dataframe to a csv file

I move on to the next file

The data is all under the correct columns for each step of the process except for within the resulting csv file. The HEADERS within that file appear to be correct but the DATA is not in order and I am not sure how to correct this.

```
#=========================================================================================
#Start of program Setup
#=========================================================================================
consolidatedHeaders = ['Part_Number', 'Inspection_Routine', 'Inspection_Machine', 'Serial_Number', 'Timestamp', 'Feature', \
                       'LTL', 'Nominal', 'UTL', 'Observation', 'Tool', 'Machine', 'Rework', 'manual_intervention']

#=========================================================================================
#Creating the Consolidated file
#For my testing purposes, this file will not exist and is created with every execution of code
#=========================================================================================

consolidatedFileName = consolidatedPath + '\\' + YYYY + MM + '.csv'
    if not os.path.exists(consolidatedFileName): #Need to create a consolidated File
        with open(consolidatedFileName, 'w+') as c:
            c.seek(0)
            c.write(', '.join(consolidatedHeaders))
            c.write('\n')
            #c.truncate()
            c.close
#=========================================================================================
#Bits of irrelevant code here finding files that are candidates for import and consolidation
#=========================================================================================


#=========================================================================================
#We've now found a file, lets go through it and add each feature and accompanying data
#to a dataframe
#=========================================================================================
df = pd.DataFrame()#consolidatedHeaders, header=0) # This will hold the ingested data, adding headers here caused problems downstream

for each do something: #not actually in code, just showing that this is a loop
#=========================================================================================
#Loop through every feature within the file and append their data to df
#=========================================================================================
    observationInfo={'Part_Number' : partNumber, \
                     'Inspection_Routine' : inspectionRoutine, \
                     'Inspection_Machine' : inspectionMachine, \
                     'Serial_Number' : serialNumber, \
                     'Timestamp' : creationDate, \
                     'Feature' : nrpSplit[0][1:], \
                     'Nominal' : nrpSplit[1].strip(), \
                     'UTL' : nrpSplit[2].strip(), \
                     'LTL' : nrpSplit[3].strip(), \
                     'Observation' : nrpLines[whileIndex + 1].strip(), \
                     'Tool' : plhFeatureDF.get_value(0, 15, takeable=True), \
                     'Machine' : plhFeatureDF.get_value(0, 16, takeable=True), \
                     'Rework' : plhFeatureDF.get_value(0, 17, takeable=True), \
                     'manual_intervention' : plhFeatureDF.get_value(0, 18, takeable=True) \
                     }
    df = df.append(observationInfo, ignore_index=True)
#=========================================================================================
#df is now complete with each feature from the prior loop
#The following 'print(df.head())' shows the data in the correct columns exactly as it
#should be in the output file
#=========================================================================================

print(df.head()) #this shows the data exactly the way it should be

#=========================================================================================
#add df with ingested data to our consolidated .csv file
#=========================================================================================

with open(consolidatedFile, 'a+') as consolidate:
    df.to_csv(consolidate, header=False, index=False)

#=========================================================================================
#Problem!! When opening the resulting .csv file, The data is all in the wrong columns. The 
#columns are not in the order of "consolidatedHeader" that i used to create the file or 
#in the order of df which is appended to the file.
#=========================================================================================
```

Comment: You need to provide I/O dataframes.

Comment: I can not do that due to our export control policy. but the input(observationInfo) series shows the headers which should transfer to the input dataframe. They all have either string or decimal values. The output is an empty dataframe that is given the same headers by the consolidatedHeaders list. I am simply wondering why this code would not write the data to a csv in the same order that it is containing the data. The input contains the data/headers in the correct order and the output has the headers in the correct order, but it is not writing the data to the file in the correct order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I needed to change

```
df = pd.DataFrame()#consolidatedHeaders, header=0)
```

to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=consolidatedHeaders)
```

This sorted the dataframe even though it was empty so the data then was appended in the correct order when I append the series to it.

For the record, on the first line(the one that did not work), I originally tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(consolidatedHeaders, header=0)
```

Which also did not work.